# How to migrate spatial tables from MSSQL to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, migration, sql-server-spatial

I'd like to migrate my spatial data from MS SQL Server to PostGIS.

Originaly the data was stored with SDE under MS SQL. Then I migrated with an ArcGIS tool.
That created a spatial data column with WKB data.

I've tried to migrate with ogr2ogr. All the data come through correctly except the geometry. I don't know why.

### Update:

- SDE 10.0
- MS SQL Server 2008 R2
- ArcGIS 10.2
- PostgreSQL 9.3 (with PostGIS)

I've tried to convert the fields with ogr2ogr:

> ogr2ogr --config PGCLIENTCODING ISO-8859-2 -f "PostgreSQL PG: "host=localhost user=postgres dbname=test password=user" -sql "SELECT *, Geometry::STGeomFromWKB([Shape].STAsBinary(),23700).STAsText() AS [geom] FROM [test].[dbo].[BARLANG_PONT]" -nln barlang_pont ODBC:intra -a_srs "EPSG:23700"

With this code the spatial field translated to WKT (varchar) text to the PostGIS. The default spatial is the `wkt_geom (geometry)` column. I could use the `-lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom` code to rename the default spatial but the two columns have different types.

Comment: Please update your question to include the version of SQL-Server, the version of ArcSDE, the version or ArcGIS, the version of PostgreSQL, and the exact process you used in data transition.

Comment: Is your data in the SDE binary format, or in MSSQL Spatial wkb format?

Comment: I would think scripting with OGR2OGR/GDAL would handle this without the extra conversion to SHP...

Comment: Foreign data wrappers could be a valid approach for this. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following steps works in nearly every case for this procedure.  It may be a good idea to repair geometry if you find this process is not producing your desired results.  There is the condition of truncated field names should they be greater than a certain length.  Generally this is not as severe a problem as the actual transfer, though.

- Open ArcGIS.
- Open your MS SQL table through ArcGIS.
- Save this table out to a shapefile.
- Close ArcGIS.
- Open  QGIS
- Open the saved shapefile
- Export the shapefile to PostGIS

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a 1-off migration, you could do it in QGIS.

1. Add the MSSQL table as a layer. 
   [image]
2. Open your DB Manager (*I had to add my PostGIS connection via the Layer->Add Layer-> Add PostGIS Layer... in order for the connection to appear in the DB Manager*)
   [image]
3. Navigate to the Postgres database that you want to import the data into.
4. Press the Import Layer button:
   [image]
5. Specify your import options and press `OK`.
   [image]
6. If all goes well, you get a success message:
   [image]
7. At this point, it is in the database but not QGIS. You can add it from the DB Manager.
   [image]

With this (or the direct OGR2OGR/GDAL) you don't end up with the truncated column names that you would have by the conversion to shapefile:
[image]